# How do I put a note after an image into an itemized environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, itemize

Following the question [How do I insert a full screen picture inside an itemized environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75467/how-do-i-insert-a-full-screen-picture-inside-an-itemized-environment), I was able to insert an image into an itemized environment. Now I would like to put comments on my slides with `\note` option, and to have it added right after the image inserted with `tikzpicture` environment (see below). Is it possible?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Szeged}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=25}   %Uncover text transparently
\setbeameroption{show notes}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1> first item
                \note<1>{some comments on first item}
            \item<3> second item
                \note<3>{some comments on second item}
            \item<4> third item
                \note<4>{some comments on third item}
        \end{itemize}
         \only<2>{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
             \fill [black] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
             \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{testPicture}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
         }
         %\note<2>{some notes on picture 1}    this does not have the expected result...       

   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

For the `[remember picture,overlay]` working properly, you have to run it twice to get it right. Then I guess it is the expected behavior you are looking for.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Szeged}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mwe} % <--- For the dummy image
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=25}   %Uncover text transparently
\setbeameroption{show notes}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1> first item
                \note<1>{some comments on first item}
            \item<3> second item
                \note<3>{some comments on second item}
            \item<4> third item
                \note<4>{some comments on third item}
        \end{itemize}
         \only<2>{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
             \fill [black] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
             \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
         }
        \note<2>{some notes on picture 1}%this does not have the expected result...       
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]